# Single MySQL Database Username on Plesk

Tags: mysql, plesk

My sys admin has me working on a server with Plesk, which requires me to have a unique username/password for each MySQL database I create.  This is very annoying, does anyone know how to create a universal username login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 10 Jan 2014** Plesk 11.5 has such functional from the box:
[image]

This may be annoying but it is for better security. Universal Username and Login might be easier to remeber but not secure. If your system admin has done then it is done for reason.

Please usually allows you to create username and databases seperately. So you can use the same username for multiple batabases.

Comment: Plesk 11.5 has ability to provide access of single user for all databases on subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) syntax, you can give a single MySQL user account access to as many databases as you want, with the same password if you'd like.

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON mydbtwo.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If you wanted to create a user that always has access to all the databases, very much like the root user, you can use syntax like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

It's not recommended to share the same username and password across projects, but you can definitely do it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to actually granting the user permissions via GRANT ALL, you'll need to add a record to the `db_users` table in the Plesk database.  Using shell to see all databases, I found the plesk database was named `psa`.  Lookup accountid from `accounts` and dbid from `data_bases`

```
INSERT into db_users VALUES('','username','accountid','dbid');
```

Comment: Using such kind of solutions can break upgrade to next Plesk version.